# How could I install epeg on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, compiling, jpeg

I've been trying to install [epeg](https://github.com/koofr/epeg) on Arch Linux, and I'm not having any success. I tried following the instructions for compiling it on the GitHub site, but I just ended up with a libepeg.so and an Epeg.h file, which I don't know what to do with. Looks like there are unfortunately no Arch packages in AUR or the repository.

Comment: What was the output of `make install`? Actually it would be helpful to have an entire log of the commands you typed and the output you got in response.

Answer (score 2):

As with all questions like this, the answer is to write a `PKGBUILD` for the package yourself (after you are done, consider putting it on the AUR to make other folks' lives easier :D).

Note, you *should not* ever manually install programs on Arch (or really any distribution with a package manager unless you are willing to deal with manually updating that package in the future). Writing your own `PKGBUILD` is really quite simple (often around 15 lines, most of which are already filled out for you), and allows you to install the package in a way so that `pacman` is aware of it; that way, updates in the future will be much simpler.

Some reading for you to get started:

- [`PKGBUILD`s](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD)
- [Basic `PKGBUILD` templates](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD_Templates)
- [Arch Packaging Standards](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_packaging_standards)

See also: `man PKGBUILD` and `man makepkg`.

If you feel you need more help, consider asking in the IRC channels (#archlinux or #archlinux-newbie) or posting on the BBS.